# Regex: How can I match third IPv4 address?

Tags: regex

I'm a regex noob and for the life of me I can't figure out how to match the third IPv4 address on line that contains three IPv4 addresses.

The line in question:

```
ip route 214.25.48.547 255.255.255.255 16.48.75.46 name Chicago-VPN
```

The regex I have so far that matches one IP:

```
([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3})
```

If I put a {3} at the end of it, it breaks.  I think it has something to do with the spaces between the addresses but I can't figure out how to handle that. I need to capture the third address.

https://regex101.com/r/mN3cR6/1

Comment: Add  a multiline modifier

Comment: It's all on one line

Comment: In regex101 put `g` in the next text field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add a multiline modifier to the code.

Your new code should be like this

`/([0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3})/g`

See this demo https://regex101.com/r/mN3cR6/2

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\s?)+
```

This should match one, two, or three, or even more "IPs".

Or

```
([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3})\s([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3})\s([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3})
```

for exactly 3.

Or

```
([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\s?){3}
```

for a shorter formula with some possible errors.

Note that the basic idea is problematic too, as it matches "999.999.999.999" when it is definitely not a valid IP address.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that the regex needs to not only contain the IPs but also the spaces between the IPs.

So adding a space into the repeated group should do the trick:

```
([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3} ){3}
```

If you don't want tat space in the final match, you make it non-greedy, using `??` (or `*?`):

```
([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3} ??){3}
```

Also note, that your regex matches more than just valid IPs. e.g. `999.999.999.999` would match nicely.

Answer (score 0):

You are already matching all three IPs with that regex.

`([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3})`

Match 1

1. 214.25.48.547

Match 2

1. 255.255.255.255

Match 3

1. 16.48.75.46

You can test it here:

http://rubular.com/

The problem may be with how you are trying to access them.

In Ruby, your regex works perfectly:

```
regex = /([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3})/
"ip route 214.25.48.547 255.255.255.255 16.48.75.46 name Chicago-VPN".scan(regex)
 => [["214.25.48.547"], ["255.255.255.255"], ["16.48.75.46"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should match the third ip

```
(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\s){2}([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3})
```

It's possible to be more compact depending what language you're using - for instance in ruby

```
string.scan(/([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3})/)[2]
```

would give you what you want.  You could also collapse the multiple [0-9]{1,3}. instances using non matching groups and counts